Data filtering in Debezium source connector (PostgreSQL)
{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
  "database.hostname": "<host>",
  "database.port": "<port>",
  "database.user": "<user>",
  "database.password": "<pw>",
  "database.dbname": "<db>",
  "topic.prefix": "FILTER4",
  "table.include.list": "<table>",
  "column.include.list": "<column>",
  "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "key.converter.schema.enable": "false",
  "value.converter.schema.enable": "false",
  "query.filter": "`<table>`.`<column>`='<value>'"
}

I have shared my sample source connector configuration, but the data is not being filtered as expected. Instead, all data from the table is being inserted into the Kafka topic.
I'm trying to identify the issue, but I'm unable to do so. Could anyone please assist me in determining if any additional configurations are needed?

What is the filter you are trying here? There is no such property as query.filter in debezium postgres source connector.
